# get dict based on key value dynamically

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I changed the question completely to make the concept easier.

I have a listed dictionary and I want to print out dictionaries that have the same `id` key value.

Here is a listed dictionary:

```
testdata = [{"id": "test1",
            "data":"book",
            "type":"work"},
            {"id": "test2",
            "data":"cd",
            "type":"school"},
            {"id": "test1",
            "data":"cd",
            "type":"school"},
            {"id": "test3",
            "data":"book",
            "type":"work"}]
```

Example question - how can I print just the dictionaries that have `test1` as the value for the `id` key?

I can do this statically by saying:

```
for r in testdata:
    if r["id"] == "test1":
        print(r)
```

**but how can I print the same thing if I didn't know the id's name before hand. how can I dynamically look for key values that have the same id and print them in a forloop or append to a new list?**

Comment: What is the expected output that you want? A list of unique company values? Please edit this information into your original question.

Comment: If you don't know that the client ID is "CompanyA", what does it mean to say "just the dicts of CompanyA"? Which company do you want just the dicts of?

Comment: Maybe you want a new dictionary whose keys are clinic IDs, and the values are the lists of dictionaries with that clinic ID?

Comment: @Barmar I changed the post to reflect the question. I already have an example of exactly what I need in the post. I just don't know how to do this dynamically. Does the example help explain exactly what I need? If you test the example and print out the result it will show you what I need.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace the literal string `"CompanyA"` with a variable?

Comment: If so, just do it. `clinic_id = input("What clinic? ")` and then `if (record['clinic_id'] == clinic_id:`

Comment: I completely changed the question to reflect the concept of what I am asking for better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ids = set((d['id'] for d in testdata))

for id_ in ids:
  print ([data for data in testdata if data['id'] == id_])

#Output:
[{'id': 'test2', 'data': 'cd', 'type': 'school'}]
[{'id': 'test3', 'data': 'book', 'type': 'work'}]
[{'id': 'test1', 'data': 'book', 'type': 'work'}, {'id': 'test1', 'data': 'cd', 'type': 'school'}]
```

sort and groupby will also do

```
from itertools import groupby

# create a func that gives the key to sort and group.
key_func = lambda d: d['id']

# First, Sort the list based on the needed field. 
sorted_test_data = sorted(testdata, key=key_func)

# Next, simply group them by the field. 
for key, group in groupby(sorted_test_data, key_func):
  print(key + " :", list(group))
```

Comment: I tested this out and this works. I changed the code so its not a one line for loop and I think I got the same thing but I am not sure:

Comment: `for company in companies:
    datam = []
    for datat in testdata:
        if datat["clinic_id"] == company:
            datam.append(datat)
    print(datam)`

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX it looks like the same, but I don't see any gain in that, list comprehensions are more readable (when kept simple)

Comment: This is true but I may be doing more to the data than just that, so I figured breaking out the 1 liner into a forloop with multi lines would be better. I may add a count variable the iteration and make tuple that shows the total amount of specific clients based on the client_id. So if there are 10 client_id's with the value companyA, then I want to append a tuple that has that total amount. I may be able to do that in a one liner but I am not sure.